# How can I restore deleted system cache in `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches`?

Tags: macos

I cleaned disk space and deleted some caches. Seems like some of the stuff in the cache folder has been used by the Mac OS (Sierra).

The **Mac OS is working**, the only thing is not working (I noticed so far) is the `rsync`, a command line utility app. When I try to run `rsync` I see the following error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec xclude: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/pipe.c(86) [sender=2.6.9]
```

How can I fix the error and restore the content of the cache folder? (I don't have Time Machine).

P.S.

If that matter, I believe the cache I deleted had different path, it didn't something like `/Library/Caches` and I don't have the `/BuildRoot` dir at all on my machine.

Comment: /BuildRoot is a part of Apple's compilation system for compiling macOS, it shouldn't exist on your computer and the only place you should see it mentioned is from error logs referring to source code.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s assume your Mac can boot and run Safari.

Go here, and download Sierra and reinstall on top - that drops a functioning system on top of your accounts, files, apps.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Assuming that didn’t work, we would need to understand the rsync command in detail and perhaps troubleshoot that, but since `rsync` comes with macOS - you likely have that from the system.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's working. I'm thinking - maybe I can just upgrade my system to latest version, instead of re-installing the same version?

Comment: For sure @AlexCraft - there’s less breakage possible when you don’t upgrade, but if you want to do that anyhow and have a backup - go for it. If I didn’t have a backup and wanted one, I’d spend the extra time to install the same version, complete a backup and then upgrade.